# populate listbox with table names

Tags: php, html

i want to populate a listbox with the table names from a database. here's the code i've written for it but it doesn't seem to work

```
<select id="arrays" name="arrays" style="width: 403px;" class="Fieldcell">
<?php
$dbname = 'myBase';

if (!mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$num_tables = mysql_num_rows($result);


for($i=0;$i<$num_tables;$i++)
{

echo "<option value=\"$row[i]\">$row[i]</option>";

}

/*while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

echo <option value=\"$row[0]\">$row[0]</option>";

}*/


mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</select>
```

Comment: 'it doesn't seem to work'. Can you explain WHAT is not working? You can easily print PHP warnings/errors to the screen. But what I can see is that your first for-loop is not complete. 'for($i=0;$i ' should be: for ($i=0;$i<$num_tables;$i++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commented out section is the section that will make it work. You are using a for loop where you are trying to loop through a variable $row that is never defined. You need to use mysql_fetch_row() to actually grab the data from the result set. Which it looks like you had, but then commented out. Nuke the for lop and uncomment the while loop. Although looks like you have a syntax error in your while loop (missing quotes). Here is what it should look like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<option value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</option>";
}
```

OR

You can keep it the way it is now, but above your for loop you need to add

```
$row = mysql_fetch_all($result);
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response , the issue is resolved and working as intended now. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<select id="arrays" style="width: 403px;" class="Fieldcell">';
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Could not connect to mysql');
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname") or die("DB error, could not list tables<br />MySQL error: ".mysql_error());
while( $r = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$r[0].'">'.$[0].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass'); //dont forget the correct password
$dbname=???; // insert the database name here
$thequery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbname");
echo '<select id="arrays" name="arrays" style="width: 403px;" class="Fieldcell">';
while($currow=mysql_fetch_array($thequery)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$currow(COLUMN NAME HERE).'">'.$currow(COLUMN NAME HERE).'</option>'; //insert the column name (the one that has the values inside)
}
echo '</select>';
```

On a side note: its not a good idea to use the database as root. Using the root account is not secure.